# How to ignore 3 first characters in column and take rest characters in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table in Oracle SQL Developer as below:

```
col1
-------
RT|12313
RT|ERT66
EG|daHH
```

And I would like to take from table above from "col1" only values after "|", so I would like to ignore 3 first characters in "col1" and take rest.

How can I do that in Oracle SQL Developer?

As a result I need:

```
col1
-----
12313
ERT66
daHH
```

Comment: What's the expected result if col1 contains `A|BC|123`?

Comment: In one place you say "ignore 3 first characters" and in another place "only values after pipe character". Are the two things one and the same? That is, will all your input strings have the same structure - length at least three, and the third character always a pipe symbol? If not, what do you **really** need - remove first three characters, or remove everything up to the pipe character, no matter where it appears? What if the third character is not a pipe? What if there are no pipe symbols anywhere in the input string?

Comment: Having delimited data in a single column is very poor design.  It violates the very first rule of data design, known as First Normal Form (you can google that).  Also I would point out that you do _not_ have a table in 'Oracle SQL Developer'.  You have a table in an Oracle _database_.   SQL Developer is simple one of several possible GUI client front-ends that access the database.  Your question has everything to do with writing SQL against the database and nothing to do with any particular client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `substr()`:

```
select substr(col1, 4)
```